# How to display row value in objject format on click on an anchor tag in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get row value in object format on click on an anchor tag within the td like {col1name:td1value,col2name:td2value,....} https://jsfiddle.net/3hu7zkhh/

**Expected Output**

```
    {
     A:ABC,
     B:DEF
    }
```

what i've tried

```
    jQuery('.green').click(function(){
                jQuery(this).closest('tr').each( function() { 

                    console.log(jQuery(this).text());
                });
    });
```

**Current Output**

```
  ABC,DEF
```

**Update**

```
     <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>DEF</td>
        <td><a class="green">Hit me</a></td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: Can you show html containing `<a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('table').on('click', '.green', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var $headerCols = $(this).closest('table').find('tr').first().children('th');
    var $cols = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');

    var result = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < $cols.length - 1; i++) {
        result[$headerCols.eq(i).text()] = $cols.eq(i).text();
    }

    console.log(result);
});
```

[See it in action](http://codepen.io/kaarel/pen/oXNREe)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var $ths = $("table tr:eq(0)").children();
$(".green").click(function(){
    var result = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function(){
        var data = {};
        data[$ths.eq($(this).index()).html()] = $(this).html();
        return data;
    }).get();
    console.log(result);
})
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/gxho50fL/)